# SQL - Select upcomping event and all the events one week from there

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with sport events.

Now I want to select the upcoming event plus all the events that take place within one week from the first event.

Can someone help me with this query?

My table looks like this (example):

```
+--------+-----------+----------------------+
|    ID  |  Name     | Date                 |
+--------+-----------+----------------------+
| 1      | u16 girls | 2015-07-08 20:00:00  |
| 2      | u18 boys  | 2015-05-26 18:45:00  |
| 3      | male 1    | 2015-05-31 20:45:00  |
| 4      | female 2  | 2015-06-02 21:00:00  | 
| 5      | u14 mixed | 2015-07-12 16:00:00  |
+--------+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

And now for example today is the 15th of may, the query should return the rows with id 2,3,4, because the other two events are more than one week later than event number 2

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  What do the tables look like?  What are the columns?  A SQL Fiddle also helps.

Comment: I've edited my post. I hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can get the date of the next event and then use date logic to get everything within a week after that:

```
select e.*
from events e cross join
     (select min(date) as nextdate from events where date >= now()) em
where e.date between em.nextdate and date_add(em.nextdate, interval 1 week);
```

Comment: Can you explain me what are you doing?

Comment: @Mike_NotGuilty . . . The subquery gets the next date in the future with an event.  The `where` clause then chooses all events between that date and one week further in the future.  (I just fixed a typo in the function name.)

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation and for the working query